# How to parse ISO 8601 using NSDateFormatter with optional milliseconds part

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to use an NSDateFormatter to parse dates that are in either of these formats

```
@"2013-02-01T14:21:00"
```

or

```
@"2013-02-01T14:21:56.345"
```

Currently I am using the below method to parse the string and return a date:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateToFormat];
```

This works fine for the first style of date but returns nil for a string that includes the milliseconds part.

I suppose I could test for the existence of the milliseconds and strip them but I was wondering if I could change the date format to treat the .SSS as optional?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I have this same problem too, server is done in .net, and .net cuts off the 000. I don't think the client (iOS) should be responsible for handling this. It should be up to the server, so the real question is how to fix .NET server to force millisconds even if they are 000

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to make optional parameters.

The usual solution is to use two formatters, one for each format.
To decide which formatter to use, you can either

1. Count the number of characters in the date string (as suggested in [Parsing a RFC 822 date with NSDateFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850824/parsing-a-rfc-822-date-with-nsdateformatter))
2. Just try both formatters and get the first non-`nil` result.

Since your date formats are similar, you can go with only one formatter and if the date string is too short, append `.000` before using the formatter.

Comment: Thanks Sulthan, I'll use this solution

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach since iOS 10 is to use `ISO8601DateFormatter` specifically created to handle all variations of ISO 8601 date strings. Please see the example below:

```
let date = Date()
var string: String

let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
string = formatter.string(from: date)

let GMT = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
let options: ISO8601DateFormatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withDashSeparatorInDate, .withColonSeparatorInTime, .withTimeZone]
string = ISO8601DateFormatter.string(from: date, timeZone: GMT, formatOptions: options)
```

And Objective-C version:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSString *string;

NSISO8601DateFormatter *formatter = [[NSISO8601DateFormatter alloc] init];
string = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

NSTimeZone *GMT = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation: @"GMT"];
NSISO8601DateFormatOptions options = NSISO8601DateFormatWithInternetDateTime | NSISO8601DateFormatWithDashSeparatorInDate | NSISO8601DateFormatWithColonSeparatorInTime | NSISO8601DateFormatWithTimeZone;
string = [NSISO8601DateFormatter stringFromDate:date timeZone:GMT formatOptions:options];
```

Comment: You know that this question has been specifically tagged Objective-C? It would be nice to add an Obj-C version into your answer.

Comment: This is a very old question and answer, but this answer does the opposite of what the question asks. The OP is looking to parse a string into a date, this answer takes a date and makes a string.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an universal parser which dropped milliseconds part.

```
@implementation JSONModel(NSPAdditions)

- (NSDate *)NSDateFromNSString:(NSString*)string {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
    NSArray* parts = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" T"]];
    if ([parts count] <= 1) {
        return [formatter dateFromString:string];
    }
    NSString *part0 = parts[0];
    NSAssert([part0 length] == [@"yyyy-MM-dd" length], @"Date format error");
    NSString *part1 = parts[1];
    if ([part1 length] > [@"HH:mm:ss" length]) {
        part1 = [part1 substringToIndex:[@"HH:mm:ss" length]];
    }
    NSString *fmted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", part0, part1];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    return [formatter dateFromString:fmted];
}

@end
```