# How to convert a string to Date in Swift2 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I am working on convert a date string to `NSDate`, but I keep getting `nil`:

```
let strDate = self.DateList[0] // "2015-10-06T15:42:34Z"
print(strDate)
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
print (dateFormatter.dateFromString(strDate))
```

And the running result is:

```
2016-05-18T14:00:54.466Z
nil
```

I dont know why, any suggestions?

Comment: This works fine for me

Comment: @Sulthan it works fine if `print(strDate)` returns `2015-10-06T15:42:34Z` but it returns `2016-05-18T14:00:54.466Z`

Comment: @Bhavin I see - maybe it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877489/how-to-parse-iso-8601-using-nsdateformatter-with-optional-milliseconds-part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got `2016-05-18T14:00:54.466Z` in a `print(strDate)`
so, Your format should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`
//---------------------------------`2016-05-18 T 14:00:54.466 Z` ----

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"  
print (dateFormatter.dateFromString(strDate))
```

Comment: It works. But how can I make it only show the date and time.  now is Optional(2016-05-18 04:00:54 +0000)

Comment: means you want to remove optional or you want it in format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Comment: @JaniceZhan check this http://blog.apoorvmote.com/convert-date-to-string-vice-versa-in-swift/

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it - just needed to escape out the 'Z':

`dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"`

Answer (score 1):

A safer solution would be to use `ZZZZZ` as the time zone specifier or you could use of of the `X` specifiers.

The difference between `Z` and `X` is basically that `X` allows for literal Z to be used when the time offset is zero. See [Date Field Symbol Table](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table)

Of course, you are also missing the millisecond part (`.SSS`). If you have two formats, one with milliseconds and one without milliseconds, you will have to use two different formatters.